# Move SSD drive with installed ubuntu 16.04 from one laptop to another

Tags: 16.04, ssd

I have ThinkPad x220 (core i5 2520M, 6GB ram, ssd 128 GB) with Ubuntu 16.04 installed and configured (development enviroment). This laptop went through a lot and I want to replace it for the same model with slightly better configuration (and better condition of course) - core i7 2620M, 8GB ram, ssd 160GB.

Question is, can I simply take my old ssd drive and place it in new laptop? Or will it cause issues with ubuntu, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple move of ssd will not allow the system to access the operating system present in the disk. You will need to configure the boot partition to the one which is present in the ssd. Else the system will not find the booting operating system.

**When moving:**

When moving you have to take care of hardware dependencies.  However most users won't encounter any difficulty other than xorg.conf (and even then modern distributions tend not to need it) and perhaps the bootloader.

- If the disk configuration is different, you may need to reconfigure
  the bootloader and filesystem tables (/etc/fstab, /etc/crypttab if
  you use cryptography, /etc/mdadm.conf if you use md RAID). For the
  bootloader, the easiest way is to pop the disk into the new machine,
  boot your distribution's live CD/USB and use its bootloader
  reparation tool.

Note that if you're copying the data rather than physically moving the disk (for example because one or both systems dual boot with Windows), it's faster and easier to copy whole partitions (with (G)Parted or dd).

- If you have an xorg.conf file to declare display-related options
  (e.g. in relation with a proprietary driver), it will need to be
  modified if the target system has a different graphics card or a
  different monitor setup. You should also install the proprietary
  driver for the target system's graphics card before moving, if
  applicable.
- If you've declared module options or blacklists in /etc/modprobe.d,
  they may need to be adjusted for the target system.

**Cloning:**

Cloning an installation involves the same hardware-related issues as moving, but there are a few more things to take care of to give the new machine a new identity.

- Edit /etc/hostname to give the new machine a new name. Search for
  other occurrences of the host name under /etc. Common locations are
  /etc/hosts (alias for 127.0.0.1) and /etc/mailname or other mail
  system configuration.
- Regenerate the ssh host key.
- Make any necessary change to the networking configuration (such as a
  static IP address).
- Change the UUID of RAID volumes (not necessary, but recommended to
  avoid confusion), e.g., mdadm -U uuid.

Comment: Great answer. I'll be physically moving the disk and the only 2 differences between those laptops are CPU (i5 vs i7) and RAM (6gb va 8GB). Both thinkpad x220.

Comment: how did this work out for you?